# how do i add a body to my delete http request

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to add a body  to my delete http request  but it seems that the http pakage doesnt accept it

```
http.delete('${config.basicUrl}removeFavorite', body: json.encode(requestBody))
```

is there any solution for this ?

Comment: I'm not going to add this as an answer, but just an FYI, from the HTTP Spec: `A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics;
   sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
   implementations to reject the request.`.  I believe I've seen the case where a load balancer rejects or doesn't pass on DELETE requests with a body, so be careful about what you do. If you have control over the server I'd re-evaluate and try to avoid a DELETE request with a body.

Comment: thank you I already knew that but i have no control to the server so i am going with the flow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  final client = http.Client();
  try {
    final response = await client.send(
        http.Request("DELETE", Uri.parse("${config.basicUrl}removeFavorite"))
          ..headers["authorization"] = "Bearer $bearer"
          ..body = "...");
    //
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
```

Comment: How can i add a header to my http request

Comment: Use `headers` attribute https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseRequest/headers.html `.headers["some-header"] = "somevalue"`

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I can use multiple header and what should I actually write in  ..body = "...")  section?

Comment: @S.M.Asif , just repeat `..headers['..'] = '..'` as many times as you need. Body is your request body, for GET request you don't need body, for POST/PUT requests it depends on what the online service you're dealing with request there should be http api docs for body samples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to be little bit more sure about the fact that - Suppose I need to set two fields in body for example: {"id":4, "status" : "done"} . Then how can I do that with body like you mentioned?

Comment: @S.M.Asif body is a string. So need to encode your data first. Most probably you're looking to [encode in json](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html), in that case `..body = jsonEncode({"id": 4, "status": "done"})`

Comment: @Ski worked beautifully, I was trying `..bodyFields = {"id": 4, "status": "done"}` do you have any ideas about why it wasn't working? thanks

Comment: @JoséFernandoGarciaJunior , `bodyFields` would work, but this does not encode into json, it will use form-encoding and your server probably does not support it. Form encoded payloads example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#Example